# Use one list to iterate and combine the objects to find files with two extensions using python

Tags: python, list, file-type

I want to iterate a list of possible extensions into two variables to find all possible matches.

With bash, this would be partially achieved like this:

```
while read ext; do
   find $DIR -type f -name "*.$ext.*"
done < extensions.txt

while read ext; do
   find $DIR -type f -name "*.*.$ext"
done < extensions.txt
```

where `extensions.txt` contains:

```
phar
php
pl
py
cgi
asp
js
html
htm
phtml
txt
gif
```

But what I want to achieve is to combine only the extensions of this one list.
For example, I want to find files like `filename.php.txt` or `filename.html.gif` and not just any type like `filename.random.extension` because this outputs too many files.

Could someone help with this?

## What I have tried so far with instructions

I placed a file in a directory `/some/www/path/html/` with the name `filename.php.txt`
I run the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from glob import glob

with open('/root/scan-files/extensions.txt', 'r') as f:
    exts = f.readlines()

for file in glob("/some/www/path/html/*.*.*"):
    if all(i in exts for i in file.split('.')[1:]):
        print(file)
```

and there is no output. It should have found the `filename.php.txt` in that path.

Tried to debug:

```
python -m pdb find-malicious-extensions.py 
> /root/scan-files/find-malicious-extensions.py(3)<module>()
-> from glob import glob
(Pdb) n
> /root/scan-files/find-malicious-extensions.py(5)<module>()
-> with open('/root/scan-files/extensions.txt', 'r') as f:
(Pdb) n
> /root/scan-files/find-malicious-extensions.py(6)<module>()
-> exts = f.readlines()
(Pdb) n
> /root/scan-files/find-malicious-extensions.py(8)<module>()
-> for file in glob("/some/www/path/html/*.*.*"):
(Pdb) n
> /root/scan-files/find-malicious-extensions.py(9)<module>()
-> if all(i in exts for i in file.split('.')[1:]):
(Pdb) n
> /root/scan-files/find-malicious-extensions.py(8)<module>()
-> for file in glob("/some/www/path/html/*.*.*"):
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /root/scan-files/find-malicious-extensions.py(8)<module>()->None
-> for file in glob("/some/www/path/html/*.*.*"):
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) n
The program finished and will be restarted
```

Any ideas where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) method from the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module:

```
from glob import glob

with open('extensions.txt', 'r') as f:
    exts = f.readlines()

for file in glob("*.*.*"):
    if all(i in exts for i in file.split('.')[1:]):
        print(file)
```

---

Breaking it down:

1. Import the `glob` method from the `glob` module:

```
from glob import glob
```

2. Open the `extensions.txt` file and store all the extensions in a list:

```
with open('extensions.txt', 'r') as f:
    exts = f.readlines()
```

3. Iterate through all the files in the current directory that has at least 2 dots in its name:

```
for file in glob("*.*.*"):
```

4. Split each file's name by a dot and check to see if all the strings, besides the first one, are among the valid extensions. If so, print the file's name:

```
    if all(i in exts for i in file.split('.')[1:]):
        print(file)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I am running this from the /root directory on the server and it doens't find anything, even when I add some fake files like filename.php.txt.

Comment: Add the path into `glob` like: `for file in glob("C:\\Users\\Tom\\Desktop\\Folder\\*.*.*"):`